# using an info button to change text dependent on text

Tags: ios, xcode, logic

Hi thanks for taking the time to see my question

I have a logic problem, I have an info button that when pressed changes the image inside a UI Image view

```
  - (IBAction)infopressed:(id)sender {

 useridtext.hidden = YES;
password.hidden = YES;

    //the original image before change is called 'login alpa'

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 2.0;
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction

    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [_login.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeImageTransition"];

    // change image
    _login.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageciren1.jpeg"];


    }
```

How can I change the image in the image view back to login alpha?  And if they were to press the button change it to imageciren1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)infopressed:(id)sender {
    static int = 0;
    NSString *imageName;
    if (i == 1) {
        imageName = @"loginalpha.jpeg";
        useridtext.hidden = NO;
        password.hidden = NO;
        i--;
    } else {
        imageName = @"imageciren1.jpeg";
        useridtext.hidden = YES;
        password.hidden = YES;
        i++;
    }
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 2.0;
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [_login.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeImageTransition"];

    // change image
    _login.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

Comment: Ok I now have a new issue, I am animating the background of the app to change after the button is hit, how can I reverse this when the button is hit again? http://sharetext.org/i9hT

Comment: Add the details about the animation to the question and I'll try to answer it

Comment: You're welcome! If it solved your problem, could you please tick it as the correct answer.

Comment: Sure, by the way, would you know much about sql and xcode (logging into a database) from an app?  If so I would love it if you could post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671543/accessing-a-databas-in-xcode

Comment: I'm sorry I don't do much server-side programming

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)infopressed:(id)sender {
    if (contactlabel.text.length)
        [contactlabel setText:@""];
    else
        [contactlabel setText:@"Test"];
}
```

Comment: Rather then changing the text of a label I am changing the background, using this code http://sharetext.org/i9hT how can I reverse the effects if the button is pressed again?