# Accessing a database in Xcode

Tags: php, sql, ios6, xcode4.5

What is the best way to access a database in Xcode? I am attempting to build an app that requires people to login with correct credentials and get certain data from the server and display it in the app.

Is there a way to write SQL in Xcode without it underlining red? To login would I access the php file with the login script?  I am not asking how, I just want some advice and some useful tips and pointers in the right direction/any useful resources for what I am trying to do?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the php file along with xcode and write the select query inside php file. in xcode create a server connection using post and provide the  path of  your php file